When using Sphinx for rst file, how to make replacement defined in rst_prolog effective in lines which are quoted by " ` "？
I‘ve defined a replacement in conf.py:
rst_prolog = """
.. |tools| replace:: Something
"""

Below is the rst file, the replacement is effective in line 1, but doesn't work for |tools| in line 4/5/7 etc., how to make the replacment happend for these lines?
1   |tools| is a community project, guided by the `CHIPS Alliance`_ under the
2   `Linux Foundation`_.
   
3   We appreciate and welcome your contributions in whatever form; please see
4   `Contributing to |tools|
5   <https://github.com/|tools|/|tools|/blob/master/docs/CONTRIBUTING.rst>`_.
6   Thanks to our `Contributors and Sponsors
7   <https://|tools|.org/guide/latest/contributors.html>`_.
   
8   |tools| also supports and encourages commercial support models and
9   organizations; please see `|tools| Commercial Support
10   <https://|tools|.org/|tools|_commercial_support>`_.

How to make the replacement happen for these lines which are quoted in " ` "?

You found a limitation of the reStructuredText format:
There is no support for nested inline markup, the rST parser will not look for a |substitution-reference| inside other inline markup like *emphasized text* or interpreted text in backticks.
(It does not matter, whether the substitution definition is in the Sphinx "rst_prolog" or in the rST source file itself.)
Support for nested inline markup is a longstanding TODO item with, unfortunately, little progress.
